# Using semantic-ui tablesort on "date" column not sorting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have a table that I'm using semantic-ui's tablesort on. The fields in the table are dates with "MM/DD/YYYY" format.

The problem is that it's sorting it as a number. So the following dates are sorted desc it doesn't take the year into account. 9/7/2016 should be last. Is there some workaround for this to have the sort use the field as date?

```
9/29/2017 
9/21/2017 
9/13/2017 
9/7/2016 
9/6/2017 
9/6/2017
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this the script can use data-sort-value="" so you can make the value a toTime() value or some other value that won't show up on table but the sort will use it for sorting by number.

Comment: do you have an example please?

Comment: just to add data-sort-value is an attribute of td check https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3120